# A search for optimal order ideals

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, coding-theory

At the behest of Gerhard Paseman I'll describe the problem that I alluded to in
[*name for a partial order*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72260/the-name-for-a-partial-order).

Let $M = M(\infty)$ denote the set of all finite subsets of the positive integers $\mathbb{N}$.  As I mentioned in my other question, $M$ has a partial order defined as follows: If $S \in M$ and $i \ge 1$ is an integer, denote by $S_i$ the $i$-th largest element of $S$.  We say that $S \ge_R T$ if $|S| \ge |T|$ and $S_i \ge T_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, |T|$.  For any finite subset $A \subset M$ define the polynomial
$$ f_A(t) := \sum_{S \in A} \sum_{T \in A} t^{|S \Delta T|},$$

where $S \Delta T$ denotes the symmetric difference.  If $ p \in (0,1)$ say that a finite subset $A \subset M$ is *optimal at $p$* if $f_A(p) \ge f_B(p)$ for all subsets $B \subset M$ with $|B| = |A|$.  Say that $A$ is *optimal*, if there is some $p \in (0,1)$ for which $A$ is optimal at $p$.  Say that $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ if there is a permutation $\pi \in S_{\infty}$ (permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ which only move a finite set of elements) and a subset $T \in M$ such that $B = \{ \pi(S) \Delta T : S \in A \}$.  It's easy to see that if $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ then $f_A(t) = f_B(t)$.

Another way of thinking of $M$ is to consider it to be infinite sequences of 0's and 1's with only a finite number of 1's (i.e. infinite bit-strings).  Then cardinality becomes Hamming weight and symmetric difference becomes exclusive or.  Isomorphic sets of bit-strings would be obtained from one another by permuting coordinates (every bit string in the set gets permuted in the same way), and then xoring everything with a common bit-string.

In  [(Gordon, Miller, Ostapenko)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.3284v2)  we proved that if $A$ is optimal then it is isomorphic to an order ideal for the order $\le_R$. For a fixed value $N$ for $|A|$ we were then able to make a search for all order ideals of size $N$, and then determine the optimal ones (for some $p$) among those.  We were able to do this by looking at the subposet of $M$ of elements $S \in M$ such that $|\{ T : T \le_R S \}| \le N$.  In particular we were interested in optimal sets whose cardinality is a power of 2.  The search for cardinality 64 took about 1/2 hour.  Unless we have a new idea the search for $N=128$ is out of the question.  For $N=64$ there are 4384627 order ideals of cardinality 64, but less than 100 of them are optimal.  Thus I was hoping that if there are theorems around about the structure of the order ideals of $M(\infty)$ that that might help us to make a more efficient search.  In the previous question, Richard Stanley pointed out that the partial order that I was using had been studied before in  [one of his papers](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/84.pdf) .

Comment: Thank you for showing this problem.  I assume in the definition of A isomorphic to B you want B= instead of A=.  Also, I apologize for an earlier error.  The partial order I and Libor Polak used involved multisets, not sets, of the positive integers.  I shall contemplate upon this problem.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.11 

Comment: Also, it is easy for me to get confused.  A in M suggests that A is a set of numbers.  A finite set A from M is a finite subset of M.  By a finite set A in M I am guessing you mean the latter, but I would expect A subset M instead of what you have, which is A in M.  Can I consider it a typo, and mentally substitue the subset symbol for the member of symbol in those places to get your meaning?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.11

Comment: @Gerhard: I fixed the typos (I think that I got all of them).  One other thing: you can also define a different partial order on subsets of M:

Say that $A \ge_D B$ if $f_A(t) \ge f_B(t)$ for all $t \in (0,1)$ (the $D$ is for dominates).  It's necessary (but not sufficient) for $A$ to be maximal in this partial order (at least restricted to sets of cardinality $|A|$) in order for it to be optimal.  I found empirically that almost all of the maximal sets for $N=64$ were optimal. 