# The size of maximal antichain for a given partial order

Tags: co.combinatorics

Now I have a partial order relation among elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2^{n}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$.
For $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$, denote
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \text{supp}(x) &= \{i \ | \ x[i] = 1, 0\le i\le n-1\} = \{i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_s\},\\
        \text{supp}(y) &= \{j \ | \ x[j] = 1, 0\le j\le n-1\} = \{j_1, j_2, \cdots, j_t\},
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
where $s$ and $t$ are positive integers, $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_s$, $j_1 < j_2 < \cdots < j_t$.
Say $x \preceq y$ if $s \leq t$ and $i_{s-k} \leq j_{t-k}$ for all $0 \leq k \leq s - 1$.

I want to know the formula of the size of maximal antichain according to $n$, the maximal cardinality of set in which any two distinct elements are incomparable.

Here are some conclusions I have obtained. Denote $S_n$ as the size of maximal antichain, then $S_n\leq \tbinom{n}{\lfloor n / 2\rfloor}$ since the partial order in Sperner’s theorem is weaker. However I can't fix out the exact formula for $S_n$. I wonder if there exist some conclusions or references.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not much less, at most by a $\sqrt{n}$ factor, since you may consider all subsets with given sum like $n(n+1)/4$, and by certain CLT there are about $\Theta(2^n/n)$ such subsets.

Comment: I think your poset is isomorphic to the one in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76723/what-is-the-size-of-a-largest-antichain-in-this-poset?rq=1. If So then it is known to be strongly Sperner by a result of Stanley, so the maximal antichain size is just the maximal rank size, and the rank generating function is known.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I think the poset $M(n)$ in  Stanley's article "Some applications of algebra to combinatorics" is exactly what I described above. However I have a pool knowledge about  the rank generating function, is there any way to get the maximal rank size from this function? There are only some conclusions about $M(n)$ in this article, is there any reference books which can help me understand better？

Comment: One reference is pages 67-71 of my book *Algebraic Combinatorics*, second ed. $S_n$ is the middle coefficient of the polynomial $(1+q)(1+q^2)\cdots (1+q^n)$. There is unlikely to be an explicit formula, but there is a known asymptotic formula $S_n \sim \sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi}}n^{-3/2}2^n$. See OEIS A025591.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A025591

Comment: Thank you for all your comments sincerely!  I think my problems are solved.

Comment: If the problems are solved, it would be nice to wrap them up into a genuine answer so that the question is no longer "unanswered". (You can even answer your own question.)